# Localstorage mistake, best way to correct?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I am still abit of a noob and I made a site with an admin panel where I made the option to change the price showed on the front page.
However I have made this with Localstorage and it works great but it probably wont show for other visitors right?

My current Localstorage code:

```
<script>
             function save(){
            var gpprice = document.getElementById('gpvalue').value;
            localStorage.setItem("price", gpprice);
             }

    </script>

    <script>
             function save3(){
            var gpprice3 = document.getElementById('gpvalue3').value;
            localStorage.setItem("price3", gpprice3);
             }

    </script>
```

And to display it on the front page:

```
            <script>
                window.onload = function() {
                    document.getElementById("product-price1").innerHTML = "$" + localStorage.getItem('price') + "/M"; 
                    document.getElementById("product-price2").innerHTML = "$" + localStorage.getItem('price3') + "/M"; 
                    }
            </script>
```

It works really good for me and I would like a similar system.

So I guess my question is how can I correct this oopsie? Should I use MySQL instead to store the value? Or is there a way to still use this?

Comment: `localStorage` is generally a poor choice (in the browser) for data related to financial (I can alter it to get it for 1 cent) - better to use a server side repository of some sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one else can access your localstorage data. You need to store it in a database.